# Trying to use PaymentKit on iOS8 with Swift

Tags: swift, stripe-payments

All,

I have added the PaymentKit into iOS8 project with Swift for Apple Pay. 
I have also added a bridging header like this :

```
#import "Stripe.h"
#import "PTKView.h"
```

I have created a new view controller swift file for Payment kit as below :

```
import UIKit

class PaymentViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

I test the application and it comes back with errors on PTKView.m like screenshot.. 
any ideas at all ? [image]

Comment: You need to include the Foundation framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foundation isn't getting imported prior to the declaration. You can see this by preprocessing PTKView.m and noting the ordering.

There are two easy workaround choices:

1) Add `@import Foundation;` prior to the declaration or
2) Move the declaration lines after the header `#import`s

Answer (score 0):

If I added the Payment Kit SDK with File -> Add files -> PaymentKit folder it worked.If i added it in directly it didn't work.